# Adding a bound to an unbounded queue

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, lock-free

I have an approximate concurrent bounded queue written in Java - it is intended to mimic the behavior of a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) except that a. it doesn't use locks and b. it only partially respects the queue's size invariant.

```
public class LockFreeBoundedQueue<T> {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final int max;

    public LockFreeBoundedQueue(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public T poll() {
        T t = queue.poll();
        if(t != null) {
            size.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return t;
    }

    public boolean offer(T t) {
        if(t == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if(size.get() < max) {
            size.incrementAndGet();
            return queue.offer(t);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int size() {
        return queue.size();
    }
}
```

If the queue used a lock to enforce the size invariant then model checking would be relatively simple in that the queue would only have three states: empty (`poll` returns null), full (`offer` returns false), and neither empty nor full.  However, it is possible for more than one thread to pass the `size.get() < max` guard while `size == (max - 1)` which will leave the queue in a state with `size > max`.  I am not familiar with how this sort of "approximate invariant" can be specified or verified.

Intuitively, given a system with `N` threads that may concurrently call `offer`, I can model the queue as though it had a precise bound of `max + N`; however if I could prove that this invariant held then I wouldn't need to ask how to prove that this invariant holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you use `if (size.incrementAndGet() < max) {` in the atomic fashion it was intended for?

```
        if (size.incrementAndGet() < max) {
            return queue.offer(t);
        } else {
            // Undo my excessive increment.
            size.decrementAndGet();
        }
```

Surely this would enforce your invariant.

Comment: For some reason I thought that this would be overzealous in enforcing the invariant, but for the life of me I can't remember the problematic order of operations - I'll see if I can figure it out after I've had my coffee, otherwise I'll accept your answer.  FWIW, I could accurately enforce the invariant with `boolean success = false; while(!success) { int oldSize = size.get(); if(oldSize < max) success = size.compareAndSet(oldSize, oldSize + 1); else return false; }`, but then I might be stuck in the retry loop for quite awhile.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot - The only issue with my suggestion is that it is possible for `size` to walk off into the sunset for a while under heavy load but when the dust settles `size` should be back to normal (due to the `else ... decrement`). It will never `offer` more than `max` though. Your loop has the benefit of avoiding that but at the expense of an unnecessary loop.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, I'm never exposing `size` - `LockFreeBoundedQueue#size` returns the internal `ConcurrentLinkedQueue#size`

Comment: Now I remember what the problem was - originally `queue.offer` preceded `size.incrementAndGet` so that `size` never overestimated the actual size, and then the [poll(timeout, timeunit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method tested `size` in its retry loop.  I've fixed this so that `poll(timeout, timeunit)` just uses `queue.poll` to determine if the internal queue is empty, and so `size` just needs to be eventually consistent - it doesn't matter if it overestimates the actual size

Comment: You might also want to consider using read/write counters instead, and calculate the size as the difference. This reduces contention and avoids an ABA problem.

Comment: @BenManes - interesting idea!